# Java - how to rotate square array (two-dimensional) by 90 degree to the right?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

So, how should it work. I input "n" and "m" to make two-dimensional matrix with n*m resolution.
I need to rotate it by 90 degrees to the right to make it somehow like that image made in paint:

[image]

I wrote some code but i cant really make it working - looks like it is easy but every time i try to get it working i get "outofboundsexception". Here it is:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s1.nextInt();
        int m = s1.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        int[][] array = new int[n][m];
        int[][] ar = new int[n][m];
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < array[n - 1].length; j++) {
                array[i][j] = s1.nextInt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("INPUT ARRAY :");
        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[n - 1].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        /* here is the main actions with the array begin*/
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < array[n - 1].length; j++) {
                ar[i][j]=array[n - j - 1][i];
            }
        }
        /*the end of actions with the array*/
        System.out.println("TASK ARRAY :");
        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rr[n - 1].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(ar[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: I haven't really ran your solution, but one apparent problem is that with ar[i][j]=array[n - j][i]; you're replacing array items without keeping their reference. Also, index "n - j" is going to cause "IndexOutOfBoundsException".

Comment: `n = 4`, so when `j = 0`, the `array[n - j]` expression means `array[4]`, which is out of bounds. You need to subtract 1: `array[n - j - 1]`

Comment: Copy/paste error: The second printing loop prints `array`, not `ar`.

Comment: @Andreas That started working, thanks to Andreas! Write "n = 4, so when j = 0, the array[n - j] expression means array[4], which is out of bounds. You need to subtract 1: array[n - j - 1] " as a solution so i could mark your answer as right!

Comment: @snow4dv It's not an answer that's useful for others, since anyone else with a similar problem won't be able to find your question, as there are no good search criteria to find it. As such, just delete the question.

Comment: @Andreas Oh, no, it doesn't. When i want to make array[1][2] it makes an exception with "-1" out of Bounds. :(   upd: i wrote "square" in the title of question, wasnt right now about the previous question)

Comment: @snow4dv Probably because a rotated 3x5 matrix is not a 3x5 matrix, but a 5x3 matrix. You need to flip the dimensions of the target array: `ar = new int[m][n];`

Comment: @Andreas thanks, got it! the Leo Aso's solution has everything in it - works with [5][3] too, but i removed the print class and input array print.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's the correct version of your program, with all the for-loop indices fixed, and the printing moved into a separate method.

```
public class Main {
    static void print(String title, int[][] array) {
        System.out.println(title);
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int m = s1.nextInt();
        int n = s1.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        int[][] array = new int[m][n];
        int[][] ar = new int[n][m];
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                array[i][j] = s1.nextInt();
            }
        }

        print("INPUT ARRAY :", array);

        /* here is the main actions with the array begin*/
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                ar[j][m - i - 1] = array[i][j];
            }
        }

        /*the end of actions with the array*/
        print("TASK ARRAY :", ar);
    }
}
```

Comment: oh ok no understanding - thanks for your services anyway

Answer (score -3):

`double x1 = point.x - center.x;
double y1 = point.y - center.y;

double x2 = x1 * Math.cos(angle) - y1 * Math.sin(angle));
double y2 = x1 * Math.sin(angle) + y1 * Math.cos(angle));

point.x = x2 + center.x;
point.y = y2 + center.y;`

That should tranform each point, it should be simple enough from there. The center is the length/2

Comment: Universal for any other angles.

Comment: You can't rotate a **matrix** by 2 degrees, so that's a moot point. Only 90, 180, or 270 degrees. It a **matrix**.

Comment: This isn't really a geometry problem.

Comment: @Andreas It still works nevertheless, and yes you can,  either ignore some values, or make the array bigger and recenter it.